# Problems while passing variable from controller to blade view

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I have a model class

```
<?php

class CategoriaModificador extends Base
{
     protected $table = 'categorias_modificadores';

public function restaurantes()
{

    return $this->hasMany('CategoriaModificadorRestaurante', 'categorias_modificadores_id');
}

}
```

When I try to pass the variable to the blade view in my controller

```
 public function show($id = 0)
{
    if (!get_session_empresa()) {
        return Redirect::route('empresa.logar')->with('message_error', 'Você precisa está logado');
    }


    $categoriaModificador = CategoriaModificador::where('empresas_id', (int)get_session_empresa()->id)
        ->where("id", (int)$id)
        ->first();

    return View::make('frontend.' . $this->theme_base . '.categoria-modificador.show')
        ->with('categoriaModificador',  $categoriaModificador);

}
```

I find this error [image: laravel error]

This is my show.blade.html

```
@extends('frontend.default.base_restrita')

@section('title')
Categoria de Modificador - {{ config_value('site_nome') }}
@stop

@section('content')

<section id="main-content">
    <section class="wrapper">
        <section class="panel">
            <header class="panel-heading">
               {{$categoriaModificador->nome}}    
            </header>
            <div class="panel-body">
                <div class="clearfix">
                  <div class="row">
                      <div class="col-lg-5">
                          <h4 class="pull-right"> Nome:</h4>
                      </div>
                      <div class="col-lg-6">
                           <h4 class="pull-left"> {{$categoriaModificador->nome}}</h4>
                      </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="row">
                      <div class="col-lg-5">
                          <h4 class="pull-right"> Obrigatório:</h4>
                      </div>
                      <div class="col-lg-6">
                           <h4 class="pull-left"> {{$categoriaModificador->obrigatorio}}</h4>
                      </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="row">
                      <div class="col-lg-5">
                          <h4 class="pull-right"> Máximo de Opções:</h4>
                      </div>
                      <div class="col-lg-6">
                           <h4 class="pull-left"> {{$categoriaModificador->maximo_opcoes}}</h4>
                      </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="row">
                      <div class="col-lg-5">
                          <h4 class="pull-right"> Restaurantes:</h4>
                      </div>
                      @for($i=0;$i<$categoriaModificador->restaurantes->count();$i++)
                        @if($i==0)
                          <div class="col-lg-6">
                              <h4 class="pull-left">{{$$categoriaModificador->restaurantes[$i]->nome}}</h4><br>
                          </div>
                        @else
                          <div class="col-lg-5">
                              <h4 class="pull-right"></h4>
                          </div>
                          <div class="col-lg-6">
                              <h4 class="pull-left">{{$$categoriaModificador->restaurantes[$i]->nome}}</h4><br>
                          </div>   
                        @endif

                      @endfor
                  </div>

                </div>
              </div>  
          </section>  
    </section>
</section>

@stop
```

Comment: Post your `show.blade.php` view please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for posting the view. I think the problem is you're using `$categoriaModificador->restaurantes[$i]->nome`, but it seems you do not have `nome` in your `$categoriaModificador->restaurantes` collection.

Also, why are you using double dollar sign with `$$categoriaModificador`?

Answer (score 0):

If you clearly look at your error, you will find your solution yourself. `Undefined variable` error means you are printing something in the view file that is not defined.

For general solution, you should check if the `variable` is defined previously or is passed to the view. This may helps other. 
Thanks